# SoP War Sphere - Can a totem be attacked?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power

Using the [Spheres of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#War) rules for pathfinder, I am wondering if the totem created by the war sphere is attackable in any way? Could a warrior come up and destroy it with a mundane weapon? What about a magical weapon? Would dispel magic work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The totem of war created by the [war](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#War) sphere is *just* a magical effect, the totem's description going into no greater detail about it than saying that a "totem is an effect" before describing the totem's mechanics. This means that the totem *can* still be removed by effects that dispel magic and that other effects that affect magical effects can alter, improve, or limit the totem of war effect, but, for example, a typical foe can't stab with his longsword the totem of war, fire an arrow at a totem of war, or render shaken through the Intimidate skill a totem of war.

This makes the totem created by the war sphere completely different from, for example, an actual, physical thing like a [totem pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totem_pole) or even a magically created physical thing that can be attacked like the shockingly similar *World of Warcraft* [shaman totems](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Shaman_totem). Best to think of the totem of war effect as like the effect of a *darkness*, *daylight*, or *silence* spell cast on a point in space.

---

***Note:*** This specific question was answered this way by the developers on the Giant in the Playground *forums somewhere in the* Spheres of Power *"Ask Me Anything" [thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?415365-The-Creator-of-Spheres-of-Power-Here-Ask-Me-Anything) and its [sequel](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?509636-Spheres-of-Power-Ask-Me-Anything-2). However, searching for the exact post is proving problematic.*

Comment: [**Question:**][1] How does a Totem looks exactly? Does it have a visual apeareance (so my allies may know if they are inside the effect?). 
Is it a physicall thing, or just a magic effect that looks like its caster wants? (A flag for example).

[**Answer:**][2] If you do not have magical signs, it doesn't appear as anything. If you do have magical signs, it would depend on the caster what it looked like.


  [1]: http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=20084873&postcount=660
  [2]: http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=20103529&postcount=672